# unblacklisting bcm4352

Tags: drivers, wireless

i blacklisted bcm4352 and rt2500 when trying to install ndiswrapper to enable me connect to a wireless network, i now cant accesss internet at all to complete the intallation , how do i remove both of them from the black list. I used sudo echo - e " blacklist bcm4352" command. The procudure i used was from this web page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper

Answer (score 0):

The full command in that link is:

```
echo -e "blacklist bcm43xx\nblacklist b43\nblacklist b43legacy\nblacklist ssb" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist
```

What `tee -a` does is append the file specified (/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist) with the contents of the "pipe" (`|`) from the output of `echo`.

The `\n` is the newline character.  So, what you output from `echo -e "blacklist bcm43xx\nblacklist b43\nblacklist b43legacy\nblacklist ssb"` is:

```
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
```

This went through the pipe and saved to the file by `tee`.

To reverse this, you have to open the file, e.g. in a terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist
```

Go to the bottom of that file, and delete those lines, and save (CTRL+S).

Comment: I managed to delete the lines but i still can't access any network.